# Ebay Scraping, filter out international results, select parents that do not have specific descendants

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

EDIT:

I have solved this thanks to @Driftr95

Here is the working code:

```
import xlwings as xw
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import statistics

@xw.func
def get_prices(url,args =[]):
    url = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url,'lxml')

    products = []
    rsecSel = 'li:not(.srp-river-answer--REWRITE_START ~ li)'
    iDetSel = f'div[id="srp-river-results"] {rsecSel} div.s-item__details'
    results = soup.select(f'{iDetSel}:not(:has(span.s-item__location))')
    for item in results:
        price = item.find('span', class_='s-item__price').text.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')

        if 'to' not in price:
            price = float(price)
            products.append(price)
    
        mean = round(statistics.mean(products), 2)
        median = round(statistics.median(products), 2)

    return mean, median
```

I now have a working function in excel that will automatically look up sold prices on ebay that I can iterate over a large amount of products instantly!

I have some code that I put together to scrape ebay sold prices using BeautifulSoup and so far it is working pretty good. The only issue I currently have is that it also pulls prices for 2 categories that ebay adds to the search results page (International Sellers, and results matching fewer words)

I am struggling to filter these out. Its like I need to identify if the listing (the parent) contains a specific descendant and then filter out that parent. I hope that is clear, here is a sample:

https://www.ebay.com/sch/57988/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Fjallraven%20nuuk%20parka&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_udlo=50&_udhi=600&LH_PrefLoc=1

The picture is an example of an item that I would like to filter out. It has a Span Class for location. This class only exists if the item is from an international seller.

```
import xlwings as xw
import bs4 as bs
import requests
import statistics

@xw.func
def get_prices(url,args =[]):
    url_base = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(url_base,'lxml')

    products = []
    results = soup.find('div', {'class': 'srp-river-results clearfix'}).find_all('div', {'class': ['s-item__details clearfix'] })
    for item in results:
        price = item.find('span', class_='s-item__price').text.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')

        if 'to' not in price:
            price = float(price)
            products.append(price)

#def calculate_averages(products):
    mean = round(statistics.mean(products), 2)
    median = round(statistics.median(products), 2)
    mode = round(statistics.mode(products), 2)

    return mean, median, mode
```

I have tried several different methods but cannot seem to filter out the parents based on a class in one of the children.

Comment: I don't understand...so what results do you want to get from that page?

Comment: I am trying to only get the "Main" results if you will. Ebay adds international results and results that are not as relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> It has a Span Class for location. This class only exists if the item is from an international seller.

Assuming the class you mean is `s-item__location` you can use [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) with the [`:has`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#has) and [`:not`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/pseudo-classes/#:not) pseudo-classes as below

```py
    iDetSel = 'div[id="srp-river-results"] div.s-item__details'
    # results = soup.select(iDetSel) # --> your current resultset
    results = soup.select(f'{iDetSel}:not(:has(span.s-item__location))')
```

or, if you want to only use `find...`:

```py
    results = soup.find_all(
        lambda r: r.name == 'div' and 
        r.get('class') == ['s-item__details', 'clearfix'] and
        r.find_parent('div', {'class': 'srp-river-results clearfix'}) and
        not r.find('span', {'class': 's-item__location'})
    )
```

(I find the `.select`-with-[CSS-selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) method much more convenient.)

---

As an example:

```py
url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/57988/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Fjallraven%20nuuk%20parka&LH_Complete=1&LH_Sold=1&_udlo=50&_udhi=600&LH_PrefLoc=1'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

iDetSel = 'div[id="srp-river-results"] div.s-item__details' 
selectors = [
    ('With Location', f'{iDetSel}:has(span.s-item__location)') , 
    ('Without Location', f'{iDetSel}:not(:has(span.s-item__location))')  
] 
for t, sel in selectors:
    print(f'\n\n{t}')
    for r in soup.select(sel):
        print('   ', ' '.join(w for w in r.get_text(' ').split() if w)) # minimize whitespace
```

prints

```
With Location
    $151.40 Best offer accepted +$16.72 shipping from Lithuania Free returns ​ Sponsored


Without Location
    $349.95 Buy It Now Free shipping ​ Sponsored
    $299.40 Was: Previous Price $499.00 40% off or Best Offer +$29.00 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $425.00 Best offer accepted +$13.45 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $329.99 Buy It Now +$19.99 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $349.30 Was: Previous Price $499.00 30% off or Best Offer +$29.00 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $296.65 Was: Previous Price $349.00 15% off Buy It Now +$20.00 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $339.99 Buy It Now +$17.87 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $361.00 Buy It Now +$10.51 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $202.00 16 bids +$25.05 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $236.00 Buy It Now +$5.99 shipping Extra 15% off ​ Sponsored
    $300.00 or Best Offer +$12.75 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $330.00 or Best Offer +$11.00 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $330.00 Best offer accepted +$11.00 shipping ​ Sponsored
    $289.00 Best offer accepted +$16.75 shipping ​ Sponsored
```

---

---

**Added EDIT:** To only get the first section, you can do

```py
    rsecSel = 'li:not(.srp-river-answer--REWRITE_START ~ li)'
    iDetSel = f'div[id="srp-river-results"] {rsecSel} div.s-item__details'
    results = soup.select(f'{iDetSel}:not(:has(span.s-item__location))')
```

(Although, since the international sellers seem to be in a separate section, the `:not(:has(span.s-item__location))` part might not be necessary...)

Comment: This is great, thanks for all the detail! I have some learning to do for sure! This takes care of the location portion of the results, now I just have to figure out how to remove the "Results matching fewer words" portion. Any tips?

Comment: @Jose sorry I missed that part of the q before -  I've added an edit to my answer

Comment: Going thru your Added EDIT now...getting a syntaxError in `results = soup.select(f'{iDetSel}`

Comment: @Jose sorry, I forgot the `f` a t the beginning of `iDetSel` (which is a formatted string now), I've fixed the edit now